# Generate Methods in Android Studio as in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have migrated from eclipse to android studio, I have been using generate delegate methods for a certain class member like this :
[image]

And the output was

[image]

is it possible to do that on android studio?

Comment: Have you tried `Alt+Enter`

Comment: @yes i have, i have also tried their Generate Delegate Methods and it doesnt do the same

Answer (score 2):

Try with cmnd+N on mac followed by generate -> Delegate Methods.
On Windows and linux Alt+Insert . (Tested only on Mac).

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio can generate methods just like Eclipse:

1. Highlight the code you want to generate method(s) from.
2. Then choose "Code" drop down menu at the top -> "Generate".

You will have the option to generate any of the following methods: 
- Constructor
- Getter
- Setter
- Getter and Setter
- equals() and hashCode()
- toString()
- override methods
- delegate methods

Also, the shortcut key combination to generate methods in Android Studio (on Windows OS) is alt + ins